# why can't I use WITH (Common Table Expressions) in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

This is just an SSCCE:

```
CREATE TABLE test(i INTEGER NOT NULL);

WITH max_i AS (SELECT MAX(i) FROM test)
SELECT * FROM test WHERE max_i - i < 2 AND max_i!=i
```

PostgreSQL complains:

```
ERROR: column "max_i" does not exist
```

I guess that's because `max_i` is a single value and not a rowset, but how do I get to define only once in my query values that I obtain through complex queries instead of having to repeat the subquery whenever they are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't reference the CTE at all in your "final" select statement. Therefor you can't reference it. Additionally the `where` condition needs to reference *columns* not tables.

In your statement `max_i` is the name of a "table", thus it cannot be used in a where condition.

```
WITH t_max AS (
   SELECT MAX(i) as max_i FROM test
)
SELECT * 
FROM test 
  CROSS JOIN t_max as t
WHERE t.max_i - test.i < 2 
  AND t.max_i <> test.i;
```

The `cross join` doesn't do any harm because we know the CTE (named `t_max`) will always return only a single row.

Once you can reference the CTE in the final select, the comparison is easy, but to do that you need to provide an alias for the column of the CTE inner select.

Answer (score 7):

First, you don't need both these conditions in the `WHERE` clause. The `i = max_id - 1` would be enough (if it worked.)

To use the value from the CTE, you either have to use a (cross) join as the other answers or use this (less common) syntax:

```
WITH max_i AS
  ( SELECT MAX(i) FROM test )
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE i = (TABLE max_i) - 1 ;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/88f6b/1)**

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could use the `table` syntax (which is a shorthand for `select * from `) as a scalar value as well.

Comment: about not needing both conditions, yeah, it's an SSCCE I just wanted to motive the case when one *might* have to refer to the expression more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
CREATE TABLE test(i INTEGER NOT NULL);

WITH max_i AS (SELECT MAX(i) Mi FROM test)
SELECT * FROM test 
JOIN max_i
on max_i.Mi - 1 = test.i;
```