# reuse result of subquery in IN operator

Tags: sql, subquery, in-operator

I found posts about reusing results from subquery, but none of them mention about IN operator

My query looks like this:

```
select count(*) 
from X
where ...
and X.id NOT IN (select id from Y)
and X.id IN (select id from Z 
             where ...
             and Z.id IN (select id from Y)
            )
```

As you see, the subquery **select id from Y** is repeated

How can I reuse the result of the subquery in the IN operator?

Comment: `IN` shouldn't matter here.  The mechanism for reusing a subquery should be the same.  Where did you see examples that didn't use `IN`?

Comment: Similar question: [why can't I use WITH (Common Table Expressions) in this query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283287/why-cant-i-use-with-common-table-expressions-in-this-query)

Comment: Also, FWIW, I don't think you need a subquery at all here.  You can write the same think using joins, and probably result in a better performing query.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right. But still, if instead of a `(select id from Y)` we have a more complex query, it would be nice to be reused - for readbility, not efficiency.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If the repeated part is as simple as that (just `select id from Y`), there may be no way to simplify it further – that would depend on the SQL product you are using. And if it's more complex, we would still need to know what your DBMS is, because different products have different capabilities and it would make little sense to give a generic answer trying to cover even just the major systems. So, I'm seconding Gordon's request: what SQL product are you using?