# What is the TABLE keyword for in this CTE expression

Tags: postgresql

in this I [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283287/why-cant-i-use-with-common-table-expressions-in-this-query) came across this weird postgres query:

```
WITH max_i AS
  ( SELECT MAX(i) FROM test )
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE i = (TABLE max_i) - 1 ;
```

It was able to use the CTE return value like a simple variable through the use of the TABLE keyword. I looked through the documentation of postgres, but I couldn't find any mention of what it is or what it is used for. Can someone explain to me how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a short way of writing

```
select * from max_i
```

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE) for details